# MySQL indexes best performance

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm optimizing a mysql table for my high traffic website and I've got a question about mysql indexes. First some info:

The table has 273382 rows.

The query is:

```
SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.idfield = table2.idfield
WHERE table1.field = 1 AND table1.field2 = 'yes'
ORDER BY table1.id DESC
LIMIT 0,25
```

I've got the following indexes:

```
index for table1.id - primary unique index
index for table1.idfield - index
index for table2.idfield - index
index for (table1.field,table1.field2) - index
```

With the above indexes query takes 1.5 to 2.5s to complete

EXPLAIN EXTENDED says it is using the primary key (table1.id), I've tried unique/index (table1.field,table1.field2,table1.id) with similar results (even though it is using this index).

During the index altering process (which takes around 1 min) the query becomes much much faster 0.009. Once the altering process is complete the query goes back to being slow at 1.5-2.5s (mostly under 2).

My question is: which index would work the best for this query and why the query is so much faster while altering the index.

Comment: general rule of thumb: any field used in a decision context (`where`, `join`, etc...) should have an index on it. and note that just having an index doesn't mean it'll be used at all times. mysql may decide that a full table scan will be more efficient than using an index.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and I've got indexes on the join and where fields, but the query is still quite slow. However during the altering process, the query run much much faster, why is that? how can I make this query run as fast as it's when it's being altered.

Comment: try with adding both table1.field and table1.field2 column into index. it might help with your  performance.

Comment: I do have that index, I also tried (table1.idfield, table1.field, table1.field2) and  (table1.idfield, table1.field, table1.field2, table1.id) - without any performance improvement

Comment: Your composite index looks like the right choice, unless most of your rows have `field=1` and `field2='yes'`, so please do a `select count(*) from ...` with your query, without the `left join` and without the `limit`). To force your index, try : `... FROM table1 force index (indexnameofyourcompositeindex) left join ...`. You can get faster with an index on table2: `table2(idfieldid, field2)`, and slightly more faster with the index `table1(field, field2, id, field1)` (but if this is worth depends on your table and data). If it doesn't work: please add the full explain.

Comment: I tried that now and it got even slower (3-4s). I don't understand how it gets so fast during the index altering process. 0.006s and the whole site is so much faster.

Answer (score 1):

If more than about 20% of the table has `table1.field = 1 AND table1.field2 = 'yes'`, then the Optimizer decides that it is cheaper to scan the table rather than bounce back and forth between even the optimal index `(field, field2, id)` and the data.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`, the size of RAM, and the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` if you want to discuss this further.

It smells like caching and I/O issues; the above info will help drill into that.